# If/else inside Foreach.. Else is ignored

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I've got a pair of Foreach loops in my script. The functions contain the requisite

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]$Logonly
```

pieces but I think my loops are using the wrong syntax to catch that switch value..

```
Foreach ($i in $is) {
    if (-not $Logonly){
        $time = (Get-Date).ToString('T')
        New-func1
        Get-func2
        Set-func3
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue "========================[ $time ]==============================="
} else {
    #Foreach ($Manager in $Managers){
        New-func1_logonly
        Get-func2
        Set-func3_logonly
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue "========================[ LogOnly ]==============================="
    }
  }
#}


Foreach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
    If (-not $Logonly){
    Remove-func4
    write-host "first remove hit"
} else {
    #ForEach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
    Remove-func5_logonly
    write-host "Second remove hit"
    }
   }
#}
```

So the way I understand it is since 3 of my functions have the aforementioned `[Parameter` line then I can call my script with a `-Logonly` and that should be enough to be caught by the else parts of the loops.  What did I do wrong here?

Current code in it's entirety:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------[Initializations]-------------------------------------------------------- 
 
#  Dot Source required Function Libraries
#. "\\server\e$\scripts\Logging_Functions.ps1" 
. "c:\users\documents\powershell\Functions\Logging_Functions.ps1"

#  Error Action
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
#  Debug preference
$global:DebugPreference = "continue"
#  WhatIf Preference, uncomment to run script in a logging only function
#$WhatIfPreference = $true

#----------------------------------------------------------[Declarations]----------------------------------------------------------
  
#  Script Version
$sScriptVersion = "1.0"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory


#  Log File Info
$sLogPath = "C:\Users\Documents\powershell\Logs"
#$sLogPath = "\\server\e$\Logs"
$sLogName = "Set-LitmosGroups_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).log"
$LogOnlyName = "C:\Users\Documents\powershell\Logs\Set-LitmosGroups (Log Only).log"
$sLogFile = Join-Path -Path $sLogPath -ChildPath $sLogName
$LogLine = $null 

#$logonly = $null

#  Variable Initializations
#  Org Unit where the target groups reside (Litmos)
$OU = "ou=test_litmos, ou=test accounts, dc=domain, dc=net"
#  Org unt containing the All Managers security group
$OU2 = "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=net"

#  Get member of the 'ALL Managers' security group
$Managers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $OU2 | Select-Object -expandproperty samaccountname

#  Get AD groups with Report to in the name in $ou
$ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" |  
Select-Object -expandproperty name

$samecount = 0
$addcount = 0

Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[Switch]$LogOnly
)

#----------------------------------------------------------[Functions]-------------------------------------------------------------


Function Get-DirectReport {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
 
        [string]  $SamAccountName,
 
        [switch]  $NoRecurse
    )
 
    BEGIN {}
 
    PROCESS {
        $UserAccount = Get-ADUser $SamAccountName -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName
        $UserAccount | select -ExpandProperty DirectReports | ForEach-Object {
            $User = Get-ADUser $_ -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName, Title, EmployeeID
            if ($null -ne $User.EmployeeID) {
                if (-not $NoRecurse) {
                    Get-DirectReport $User.SamAccountName
                }
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    SamAccountName    = $User.SamAccountName
                    UserPrincipalName = $User.UserPrincipalName
                    DisplayName       = $User.DisplayName
                    Manager           = $UserAccount.DisplayName
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    END {}
 
}

Function New-bhReportToGroup {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $Log1 = "New group for " + $manager + " has been created."
    $Log2 = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists."
    #From on when you see the below line $script:<variable> that sets the scope for that variable to the entire script which means other functions can use the value
    $script:ReportsTo = $ReportsTo -replace ("Report to ", "")

    if ($manager -notin $ReportsTo) { 
        new-adgroup -name "Report to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou
        $script:addcount = $addcount +1
        $LogLine = $Log1
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $script:samecount = $samecount + 1
        $LogLine = $Log2
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function New-bhReportToGroup_logonly {
    #[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    $Log1 = "New group for " + $manager + " would have been created in $OU."
    $Log2 = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists in $OU."
    $script:ReportsTo = $ReportsTo -replace ("Report to ", "")

    if ($manager -notin $ReportsTo) { 
        $Script:addcount = $addcount +1
        $LogLine = $Log1
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyName -LineValue $LogLine 
    }


    else {
        $Script:samecount = $samecount + 1
        $LogLine = $Log2
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyName -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function Get-bhDReports {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $script:directreports = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object samAccountName
    if ($null -ne $directreports) {        
        $LogLine = "Gathering direct reports for " + $manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = $manager + " has no reports."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }   
}

Function Set-bhRTGmembers {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    #  Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.Name -members $DirectReports
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.name -members $Manager
        $LogLine = "Report to " + $Manager + " updated."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = "Could not find group for " + $Manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function Set-bhRTGmembers_logonly {
    #[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    #  Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        $LogLine = "Report to " + $Manager + " would be updated with $DirectReports."
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyName -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = "Could not find group for " + $Manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyName -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}

Function Remove-bhOOSGroups {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $report = $report -replace ("Report to ", "")
    if ($Report -notin $managers) {
        Remove-ADGroup -Identity "Report to $Report" -confirm:$false
        $LogLine = $report + " user has fell out of scope, Report group removed."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
    else {
       Continue
    }
}

Function Remove-bhOOSGroups_logonly {
    #[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)] 
    $report = $report -replace ("Report to ", "")
    if ($Report -notin $managers) {
        $LogLine = $report + " user has fell out of scope, Report group would be removed."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
    else {
       Continue
    }
}

#----------------------------------------------[ Execution ]------------------------------------------------



Foreach ($Manager in $Managers) {
    if (-not $LogOnly) {
    $time = (Get-Date).ToString('T')
        write-host $Logonly
        New-bhReportToGroup
        Get-bhDReports
        Set-bhRTGmembers
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue "========================[ $time ]==============================="
 } else {
      write-host $logonly
        New-bhReportToGroup_logonly
        Get-bhDReports
        Set-bhRTGmembers_logonly
        Log-Write -LogPath $LogOnlyName -LineValue "========================[ LogOnly ]==============================="  
    }
  }
Foreach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
    If (-not $LogOnly){
    Remove-bhOOSGroups
} else {
    #ForEach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
    Remove-bhOOSGroups_logonly
        }
   }
#}
```

Comment: this >>> `Remove-func5_logonly` <<< looks wrong. should that underscore be replaced with a space and a hyphen?

Comment: That is the name of my logonly function(s).  To help discern them I added the _logonly to the Function name.

Comment: Is your switch parameter enclosed in a param() statement? It's not clear what errors you are getting. Can you please post the current error output that you're getting when you run the script?

Comment: ah! i misread that. [*blush*] ///// take a look here at how to check if a parameter was used >>> How to check if a PowerShell switch parameter is absent or false - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809557/how-to-check-if-a-powershell-switch-parameter-is-absent-or-false/56809663

Comment: @Efie I'm not getting an error persay but if I set DebugPref to $true and run the script in teh ISE with -logonly I never see the logonly functions get ran.  Also my first code block is exactly how the Switch is in each of the affected functions. Did I call it wrong?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I will def check that out.

Comment: Yes you need to write it like ```param( [switch]$MySwitch) otherwise you are just defining a variable during script execution, rather than setting it as a parameter for the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to declare `$LogOnly` as a parameter of the *script* - so that you can [forward it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1#example-2-forward-parameters-using-psboundparameters) to the functions you define *when you execute them*:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [switch]$LogOnly
)

function New-Thing {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$LogOnly
  )

  if(-not $LogOnly) {
    return "Thing"
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "Here I would have returned thing!"
  }
}

# Splatting $PSBoundParameters 
New-Thing @PSBoundParameters
```

As you can see, the `if`/`else` statements are no longer required - we just pass whatever parameter arguments was passed to the script along to the function.

---

If splatting `$PSBoundParameters` is undesirable (this might be the case if you have different parameters to forward to different functions), you can also [use `$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values) to make your functions take on the parameter arguments, like this:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [switch]$LogOnly,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [string]$AnotherParameter
)

# Set default param values for your custom functions
$PSDefaultParameterValues['New-Thing:LogOnly'] = $LogOnly
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Get-AnotherThing:UnrelatedParameter'] = $AnotherParameter

function New-Thing {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$LogOnly
  )

  # ...
}

function Get-AnotherThing {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$UnrelatedParameter
  )

  # ...
}

# No need to explicitly pass arguments to the functions anymore
# PowerShell will do it for us
New-Thing
Get-AnotherThing
```

---

If you insist on maintaining two sets of functions, it's as simple as:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [switch]$LogOnly
)

foreach($Round in 1..5){
  if(-not $LogOnly){
    Write-Host "Round $Round!"
    # Call Function1 here

  }
  else{
    Write-Host "Round $Round, LogOnly!"
    # Call Function1_LogOnly here
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not comfortable redoing all my functions so I'd like to keep the LogOnly ones in play. I did move my Param block back to the top above the functions but currently it's still ignoring the switch when used.

Comment: @Skeer I've added an ultra simple example at the end, please try saving it as `script.ps1` and invoke with `.\script.ps1 -LogOnly`, and see if that doesn't work as expected

Comment: Yeah your sample worked perfectly. If I change my script back to `if(-not $LogOnly)` it still refuses to run with the switch though...

Comment: @Skeer Can you post _the exact script_ that you're having issues with? Not snippets, not individual lines, but the whole script from first to last line

Comment: @Skeer The "Current Code" example you've posted _does not have a `param()` block_ - add it if you want PowerShell to recognize `-LogOnly`

Comment: Continued thanks! I edited the post with the entire script per your request.

Comment: @Skeer Good, now take the `param(...)` block that's currently sitting in the middle of the script, and _move those 4 lines to the very top of the script_ - nothing should be above it. Save as `scriptName.ps1` and then invoke with `.\scriptName.ps1 -LogOnly` and it will work

Comment: Are you kidding me? That was it?  Sometimes I swear I couldn't be duller. All the sites I've found I never once saw it stated the param block needed to be above everything else. You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: @Skeer I most certainly am not kidding you ^_^ order matters. The "full" order would be: Requires comments, Using directives, param block attributes (including `CmdletBinding`), param block, _and then the script_ itself - since you have none of the first three categories, `param()` _must_ go first :-) Happy to hear you got it working now!

Answer (score 1):

In PS to check if `[switch]` was used as parameter (using `[switch]$LogOnly` for this example):

```
if($LogOnly.IsPresent)
{
   #Do Something
}
else
{
   #Do Something else
}
```

Edit: Not sure what you're doing wrong, maybe the way you're calling your script or maybe because you're using ISE without clearing the param variables before running the script. Switch itself works fine in a param block in or out a function:

```
PS C:\> cat $home\documents\test.ps1
param(
    [string]$Test,
    [switch]$TestSwitch
)

if($TestSwitch.IsPresent)
{
    return "Hello $Test, switch is present."
}
else
{
    return "Hello $Test, switch is not present."
}
PS C:\> . $home\documents\test.ps1 -Test World -TestSwitch
Hello World, switch is present.
PS C:\> . $home\documents\test.ps1 -Test World
Hello World, switch is not present.
PS C:\>
```

Comment: This is not working for me.. neither does `if($logonly -eq $true)` and `if($logonly -ne $null)`